# JPA query with two left join

Tags: java, jpa, inheritance, left-join

I have three classes: A.java, B.java and C.java. A and B extend C. How do I write a JPA query to works correctly? I tried

```
Query query = em.createQuery("select c from C c left join A a left join B b where (c.id = a.id or c.id = b.id)");
```

Comment: How would you try to write this in vanilla SQL?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: How can anyone comment on that without seeing the classes and the relations?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you don't. In JPA:

> The default strategy, InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE, is used if the @Inheritance annotation is not specified on the root class of the entity hierarchy

When you select everything from table C, the JPA provider will instantiate classes based on the `discriminator column`, so

```
List<C> rl = em.createQuery("select c from C c", C.class).getResultList();
System.out.println(rl);
```

will give you:

```
Hibernate: select c0_.id as id2_0_, c0_.DTYPE as DTYPE1_0_ from C c0
[model.C@2cac4385, model.A@6731787b, model.B@16f7b4af]
```

If you need to you can use the `instanceof` operator in Java to determine the result types. If you want a specific subclass, then just query it:

```
List<A> rl = em.createQuery("select a from A a", A.class).getResultList();
System.out.println(rl);
```

which will give you:

```
Hibernate: select a0_.id as id2_0_ from C a0_ where a0_.DTYPE='A'
[model.A@3fc9dfc5]
```

Reference: [Entity Inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqn.html)